# Multiple Criteria Search Based Off User Input

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am currently working on a small project that involves using JDBC to hook into a small MySQL database. It's a small app that has multiple JTextFields and some JComboBoxes that can be used to add a new user to the database, update a user, delete a user and search for a user.

The search should be able to be ran when the user presses the find button and will look to see which of the fields the user filled out and then build the query off of those fields. An example would be the user is searching for someone based on first and last name:

```
String query = SELECT * FROM members WHERE firstName = ... and Surname = ...
```

The firstName and Surname fields were appended when the program detected that the user had filled out those fields with data to be searched on.

My problem is, I am trying to find an efficient way of being able to search off multiple criteria without ending up with an anti-pattern arrowhead.  Ex. I don't want my code to look like:

```
if( firstName.getText().length() > 0 )
{
  do_something();

   if( lastName.getText().length() > 0 )
   {
     do_something();

     if( email.getText().length() > 0 )
     {
         do_something();
     }
   }
}
```

etc...but so far this is the only way I can think of doing it, which will be monstrous due to the possible combination of search criteria. I was thinking of maybe doing a switch which *might*(?) help but I don't know what to base the switch off.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do the 'if' statements need to be nested?  You could simply have repeated calls to appendtoquerystring(), and have the check for length in that.

Comment: @racraman Well for one that method doesn't even exist, so I should change that. Two, why wouldn't they need to be nested? Wouldn't you still have to test to see if the user filled out a field and append?

Comment: They shouldn't be nested.  The code above, if the user didn't give first name, then you'll ignore the lastname and email that he did provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you utilize `java.awt.panel`, you can try something like

```
for(Component component : myPanel.getComponents()) {
  if(component instanceof JTextField) {
    JTextField textField = (JTextField) component;   
    buildYourSearchQuery(textField.getText());
  }
}
```